# Play framework Scala json validation null pointer exception

Tags: scala, playframework

I have this json:

```
{"arguments":["test"]}
```

I'm trying to parse it like this:

```
implicit val argumentReads: Reads[List[String]] = (JsPath \ "arguments").read[List[String]]
json.validate[List[String]](argumentReads)
```

And this causes null pointer exception error.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Add the exception details and print the `json` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
implicit val argumentReads: Reads[List[String]] = (JsPath \ "arguments").read(Reads.list[String])
```